# Sequences of powers in different modulos, what orderings can we find in them?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The sequence $x, x^2, x^3, \dots , x^p$ in modulo $p$ seems kind of random. For example when $p = 23$ and $x=7$, we have

> 7, 3, 21, 9, 17, 4, 5, 12, 15, 13, 22, 16, 20, 2, 14, 6, 19, 18, 11, 8, 10, 1

In these sort of cases when we have a primitive root, $1$ only comes in the end. But for other values $1$ can also appear in the middle (but then we don't have all the numbers appering). Is there some limitation to what numbers can appear in these cases? For example ($p=29, x=5$)

> 5, 25, 9, 16, 22, 23, 28, 24, 4, 20, 13, 7, 6, 1, 5, 25, 9, 16, 22, 23, 28, 24, 4, 20, 13, 7, 6, 1

My question is: If we have a (finite) sequence $a=(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_m)$ of different natural numbers, is it always possible to find some numbers $p$ and $x$ such that $a$ is part of (a subsequence with adjacent indeces) the power sequence $(x^n \mod p)_{n=1}^p$?

As an example: we can find $(4, 5, 12,15,13)$ in the first case above.

---

EDIT:

We can't find for example $(1,2,3)$: if $x^t = 1 \mod p$ and $x^{t+1}=2$, then $x=2$, since $x \in \{1,2,\dots, p\}$. Hence $x^{t+2}=4$, which can't be $3$ in any modulo.

It would be interesting to know some characterization for what sequenceses can appear and what can't.

Comment: the series repeats after the first 1 occurs

Comment: @avz2611 Yes, but does that rule out some cases for $a$?

Comment: looking at a series i can comment but  in general i might not be able to. for example the series you gave wont work